# DatetimePicker not updating SelectedDate

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I've got an issue with a WPF `DatePicker`.

There are two `DatePicker` controls on the form, based on a `StaticResource` `DateTheme`. The `DateTheme` looks like:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}" x:Key="DateTheme" >
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
                    <DatePicker DisplayDate="{TemplateBinding Property=DisplayDate}" SelectedDate="{TemplateBinding Property=SelectedDate}" Background="#353340" Foreground="Black"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The `DatePicker`'s just look like:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="dtpFrom" Style="{StaticResource DateTheme}" />
<DatePicker x:Name="dtpTo" Style="{StaticResource DateTheme}" />
```

And the `DateTheme` is inclided in app.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="DateTheme.xaml" />
```

But after selecting a new date and click a button the old date is still used in the code. `SelectedDate` does not update in the control.

Here the `SelectedDate` is still the old date while the new selected date is displayed on screen:

```
if (dtpFrom.SelectedDate > dtpTo.SelectedDate)
```

How to actually change the `SelectedDate` when selecting a new date in a standard `DateTimePicker` control?

Comment: What is the actual issue you are trying to solve? From your description it looks like you want both `DatePicker`s to display the same date, but without any context it is hard to guess an appropriate solution.

Comment: The issue is that after selecting a new date and click a button you get the old date in the code. SelectedDate does not update in the control.

Comment: Why `TemplateBinding` instead of `Binding`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not work because [`TemplateBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) does not support two-way bindings.

> A `TemplateBinding` is an optimized form of a Binding for template scenarios, analogous to a `Binding` constructed with `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}`. **A `TemplateBinding` is always a one-way binding**, even if properties involved default to two-way binding.

If you use a relative source binding to `TemplatedParent` instead, it will work (**but do not do it**).

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}" x:Key="DateTheme" >
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
            <DatePicker DisplayDate="{Binding DisplayDate,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        Background="#353340"
                        Foreground="Black"/>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

However, that **is not the right approach**. You should not put a `DatePicker` in a control template for itself. Control templates should be built from basic elements to make up the visual appearance of the control, not the control itself. This can lead to errors due to recursion.

In this case it is also unnecessary, since a simple style with two setters will get you the same result.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}" x:Key="DateTheme" >
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="#353340"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: oh that easy! don't use control template at all :) thanks!